# replace <f:all /> tag with normal fields on custom template grails

Tags: templates, grails, scaffold

i install templates in grails 3 and files are in src/main/templates/scaffoldind works fine but use tag

```
<f:all bean="${propertyName}"/>
```

I need a bootsrap twitter class on all inputs and f:all tag do not allow this function, so i need replace tag with individual fields, something like:

```
    <%
    props.each{
    %>
    <f:field bean="${propertyName}" property="${it.name}">
     <g:textField name="${it.name}" value="${propertyName}?.${it.name}" class="form-control" />
    </f:field>
...
    <%
    }
    %>
```

I found this article http://www.jakusys.de/blog/2008/12/grails-scaffolding-in-depth/ but is for grails 2 not grails 3, some solution for replace f:all tag for normal inputs or add class "form-control" to all f:all inputs

Comment: Hi Were you able to solve the problem. Can you please share the code as the below suggested approach doesn't seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make all fields rendered by `<f:all />` look nice and bootstrappy, you'll need to create `_field.gsp` templates for them.

You can create common templates (used for all fields) by creating these four gsp fragments:

```
_wrapper.gsp
_widget.gsp
_displayWrapper.gsp
_displayWidget.gsp
```

in this directory:

```
grails-app/views/_fields/default/
```

You can then replace the

```
<%
props.each{
%>
<f:field bean="${propertyName}" property="${it.name}">
 <g:textField name="${it.name}" value="${propertyName}?.${it.name}" class="form-control" />
</f:field>
...
<%
}
%>
```

bit in your scaffolding gsp with a call to the `<f:all />` tag.

See documentation [here](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html)

Comment: It works, but i try use. <f:field bean="${class (acording to properties in documentation)}" property="${propertyName}"> on _wrapper.gsp returns error you can give an example of the code? please

Comment: Hey rcgeorge23, I am relatively new to Grails....Could give some example of these _wrapper.gsp,_widget.gsp, _displayWrapper.gsp, _displayWidget.gsp

Comment: Also if I create these common template gsp and then try to generate-view for a domain class then will the f:all tag be there in generated edit and create gsp?

Comment: where do i get the sample of _displayWrapper.gsp ?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work for `<f:display bean="${propertyName}" />` with me when I was trying to show all properties (without editing), so here is what I did to get works properly, I've created two files the first `/views/_fields/default/_displayWidget.gsp` with this template:

```
<tr class="prop">
    <td valign="top" class="name">${label}</td>
    <td valign="top" class="value">${value}</td>
</tr>
```

and the second `/views/templates/_fields/_list.gsp` using this template:

```
<g:each in="${domainProperties}" var="p">
    ${body(p)}
</g:each>
```

Actually I've just overwrite the original template [_list.gsp](https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/804c34e91505edad88d03a7855e7aa3e925dc055/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_list.gsp) (I'm using grails v3.1).